# How to exclude file type from build in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, mocking

In an Angular 9 project, I am working with two environments: production & mock.

I want that:

- WHEN I run `ng build --prod`
- THEN the mock files should not be included in the js bundle.

I am using the extension `.mock.ts` for mock files and creating `mocks` folders so they are easier to filter.

I think this can be done with webpack, but I can't make it :(

Project **structure**:

```
|- app
  |- integration
    |- country
      |- mocks
        get-countries.mock.ts
      country.service.ts
    |- device
      |- mocks
        get-devices.mock.ts
      device.service.ts
```

This is the build configuration I have in my **angular.json** file:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        ...
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
        },
        "mock": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.mock.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
}
```

And this is my **webpack.config.js**:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  // make sure the source maps work
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  // webpack will transpile TS and JS files
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: ['/node_modules/', '/src/app/integration'],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only solution I've found was to create mock services, so the mock files will only be used in this mock services.

Depending on the environment, if production, these services are not injected in the module, so the mocks aren't either.

```
|- app
  |- integration
    |- country
      |- mocks
        get-countries.mock.ts
      country.service.mock.ts
      country.service.ts
    |- device
      |- mocks
        get-devices.mock.ts
      device.service.mock.ts
      device.service.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

The tsconfig.app.json file in the src folder has a specific exclude section for this. if your mocks directory is located outside of your src you'll have to try the main tsconfig.json in your root directory of the project.

Comment: I have tried adding `"exclude": ["**/mocks/","**.mock.ts"],` to my tsconfig.app.json but mocks are still inside bundle.  Can you post an example? Thanks!

Comment: Close, try `"**/*.mock.ts"`

Comment: Didn't work. My tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "exclude": ["**/*.mock.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this

"exclude": ["**/*.mock.ts"]

Comment: Didn't work.
I've tried to add that to tsconfig.app.json, tsconfig.json and webpack.config.js